# Overlaying multiple images in matlab efficiently

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics

I'm trying to draw multiple images on top of each other in a single matlab figure to create a panorama. The code I have works but it simply uses `image(im, x, y)` in a for loop to overlay the images.

Because I have so many images, this results in matlab having to to a lot of alpha blending and in short order the drawing slows to a crawl.

I need a way to flatten the images I've drawn so far into a single image that I can blit to the figure as a background efficiently.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
Alternatively, is there a way to use image(im, x, y) or something similar to draw to a matrix buffer in the background and then draw that single buffer to the figure?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help your speed but it might after you have finished the process.

You can use

```
saveas(figureHandle, 'filename', 'filetype')
```

to save a figure to a picture file. You could then close your current figure using `close all` and re apply the new picture as you were previously except that now it will be a single image.

Do this every couple of pictures and it might speed up your program. It will definitely speed up your viewing of the pictures.

Comment: Saving to file is just too slow to make this practical, though it is something like what I want to do.

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile So is it too slow to do overall or too slow to visualise. Because this will take ages to formulate the picture but it will be quick to view when it is done.

Comment: I need to display the results in near-real time as the panorama is being composited. So as each new image is added I need to display the panaroma thus far.

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile Yeah, then my thing definitely wont help you. Do you have some sample code that I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

You might create a single image that is the composite of all the images (especially since it appears you have no transparency). Then Matlab will only render one image at a time, instead of computing over many.  You would have to define up front what your boundaries will be, in case you need to clip. After that, you just replace the pixels with new ones (in memory, not on disk). Whether that is possible depends on what kind of pictures you are drawing. If it's hard, then a variation of Ben's method would work - using the  `getframe` function (see [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html)). It takes a snapshot of your figure, which you can then draw back to the screen. While it is usually for creating movies, there's no reason why it wouldn't work in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the blog post: [Blend images with MATLAB](http://imageprocessingblog.com/blend-images-with-matlab/), with nice examples (including a multiple images overlay), and the MATLAB code.

Comment: Stackoverflow answers are meant to be standalone.  Please include any relevant information from the link you cited in your post.